# How to get better text classification accuracy using deep learning and word2vec features>

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, word2vec, text-classification

I am trying to perform ***text classification on Roman Urdu Dataset using word2vec word embedding and deep learning model***. My approach is based on first of all

- loading the corpus and cleaning the data, tokenize the sentences and
  later sentences to words.
- The tokenized data are being trained on word2vec model using gensim
  library having vector size 300 and window size 3.
- Later these word    embedding are  used to get the feature vector for
  each document by    getting mean of word vector.
- After that the acquired doc vectors are being split into training and
  testing data and finally sent to deep learning model to text
  classification (Positive,Negative, Neutral).

***I am getting an accuracy of not more than 44% can anyone suggest what is wrong with my approach.***

Below is my code for reference.

```
model_w2v = Word2Vec(sentences = sentences, size = 500, sg = 1, window = 3, min_count = 1, iter = 10, workers = Pool()._processes)
model_w2v.init_sims(replace = True)
```

Creating doc vectors (by taking mean of word vectors):

```
docs_vectors = pd.DataFrame()
#stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english') # removing stop words
stopwords = ['hai','nhi','main','tum']
for doc in yelp['Reviews'].str.lower().str.replace('[^a-z ]', ''): # looping through each document and cleaning it
    temp = pd.DataFrame()  # creating a temporary dataframe(store value for 1st doc & for 2nd doc remove the details of 1st & proced through 2nd and so on..)
    dx = cleaner(word_tokenize(doc))
    for word in dx: # looping through each word of a single document and spliting through space
        #if word not in stopwords: # if word is not present in stopwords then (try)
        try:
          word_vec = model_w2v[word] # if word is present in embeddings(goole provides weights associate with words(300)) then proceed
          temp = temp.append(pd.Series(word_vec), ignore_index = True) # if word is present then append it to temporary dataframe
        except:
          pass
    doc_vector = temp.mean() # take the average of each column(w0, w1, w2,........w300)
    docs_vectors = docs_vectors.append(doc_vector, ignore_index = True) # append each document value to the final dataframe

docs_vectors.shape
```

**My deep learning model:**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)
# load the dataset but only keep the top n words, zero the rest
top_words = 32401
##(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=top_words)
# truncate and pad input sequences
max_review_length = 500
#X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_review_length)
#X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_review_length)
# create the model
embedding_vecor_length = 32
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_length))
model.add(LSTM(120))
#model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
#model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=3, batch_size=64)
# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

Comment: How much data do you have? Why are you doing the `init_sims()`, and have you also tried without that step? Why are you using the non-default `min_count=1`?

Comment: How is your test accuracy compared to test accuracy? Your model can be overfitting.

Comment: @gojomo I just used `init_sims()` as an optional to restrict the model to be further trained and make it memory efficient as well. Yes i have also tried without this option but still the same accuracy score. I have almost **20147 annotated docs data**.

Comment: @Jindřich the train and test accuracy is almost same with little change. Would you please elucidate how it is a problem of overfitting. Does my model closely fit if yes then how?

Comment: How many words, in total, are in those 20147 training documents, and how many unique words get word-vectors at the end of training? (This would be visible in INFO logging output or as `len(model_w2v.wv.index2entity`.) I would suggest **not** doing the `init_sims()` unless it definitely helps your evaluations. (It won't even necessarily save any memory, unless you are also doing `most_similar()` lookups.) Why are you using the non-default `min_count=1`?

Comment: The total no. of **unique words or vocabulary are 5805**, whereas, the total no. of **tokens are 261,985**. I set `min_cont = 1` to consider the doc with single word too. However,  i have also used with default setting which is `min_count=5`.

Comment: @gojomo would you identify where am I wrong with this model.

Comment: That's a tiny amount of data for the word2vec algorithm. Smaller data may not get good results, and definitely can't support larger models – like one with 500-dimensional words. And if some of those 5805 unique words only have 1 occurence, they won't get good vectors. (Good word vectors arise from a variety of subtly-contrasting word usages - without at least a handful, and ideally dozens, of varied usage examples, a word's vector will tend to be weak & only representative of whatever few idiosyncratic uses you have.

Comment: Try a `min_count` of at least 2, a vector `size` no larger than `sqrt(count_of_unique_words)`, and perhaps more `epochs` and a larger `window`, and you may get somewhat stronger results to match your limited data.